# How to add "itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" in drupal 7

Tags: drupal

This function_preprocess loaded css clases in block.tpl.php. How do I add the **same div** as other attributes as itemscope `itemtype="http://schema.org/Periodical", itemprop="image", itemprop="description" and more... Microdata elements`

```
function floyd_preprocess_region(&$variables, $hook) {
    if($variables['region'] == "top_c"){
        $variables['classes_array'][] = 'uk-margin-top uk-margin-bottom uk- grid-width-small-1-1 uk-grid-width-medium-1-3 uk-grid-width-large-1-4';
}
```

---

" **itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"**>

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
$variables['classes_array'][] = ...
```

try:

```
$variables['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = ...
```

and if it's a block, i think you should try this hook instead:

```
function floyd_preprocess_block(&$variables, $hook) {...}
```

(block instead of region)